# Align after \therefore

Tags: amsmath, amssymb

If I place my alignment ampersand after a therefore symbol (from amssymb), the proper spacing between the therefore and the rest of the equation is lost. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Ex:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\text{Characteristic equation: } &r^2 + \lambda^2 c^2 = 0\\
\therefore &r = \pm\lambda ci
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

(as compared to placing the ampersand before the therefore symbol)

Comment: Use `\therefore{} &r = \pmλci`. If you want, add some space too: `\therefore{}\quad &r = \pmλci`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert a `{}` between `\therefore` and the `&` alignment symbol. This restores the proper space of a *binary relation*.

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Characteristic equation: } &r^2 + \lambda^2 c^2 = 0\\
\therefore{}&r = \pm\lambda ci
\end{align*}
```

produces

[image]

instead of

[image]

This approach is useful whenever we use symbols defined with `\mathrel` or `\mathbin` followed by a `&` alignment symbol. In this case `\therefore` is defined in `amssymb.sty` with `\mathrel`.